# How to use props within UseEffect of the child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want the Child Component to fetch a Firebase Collection based on the props i passed through the parent. The problem is that when i try to fetch my props in the UseEffect() of my Child Component it is undefined.

I`ve tried

```js
export default function Parent(){

  const [activeUser, setActiveUser] = useState();
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  
  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    let tempUsers = [];
    await Firebase.firestore().collection('users').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        tempUsers.push({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        })
      });
    })
    setUsers(tempUsers);      
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers().then(() => {
      setActiveUser(users[0]);
      setIsLoading(false);
    })
  },[]);
  
  if(isLoading){
    <View>
      <Text>Loading...</Text>
    </View>
  }else{
    return (
      <View>
        <Child user={activeUser} />
      </View>
    )
  }   
}
```

```js
export default function Child(props){
      
  useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.user)
  }, []) // I even tried something like [props | props.user] but nothing helped :/

  ...

   }
```

Why is my props.user undefined?

Comment: The `useEffect` in the child will only be executed once, since you passed `[]` as the second parameter. Since the parent is asynchronously fetching the user and then passing it into the child, it'll miss the updated value. Changing the `[]` to `[props.user]`, or just consuming `props.user` in your function body should do the trick.

Comment: I see you tried this.. Did you put a breakpoint in the Parent component and verify that the call to `setActiveUser` is actually getting executed (and with an non-undefined value?)

Comment: Try `if (isLoading || !activeUser)`

Answer (score 1):

Very likely because `useEffect()` is SYNCHRONOUS and your `fetchUser()` is ASYNCHRONOUS.  You will need to put the `fetchUsers()` call in a closure within the `useEffect()` to allow it to complete, and you need to make your child *tolerant* of `user` being undefined until the result comes in. Also note there is no guarantee of the ORDER that `SetActiveUser()` and `SetIsLoading()` will apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding users as a dependecy in useeffect of parent function and props.user as dependecy in useeffect of child.